# Flutter SliverList with horizontal scrolling and sticky header

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I've been trying for a while now but I cannot get it to work.

I want to create a list view in a `CustomScrollView` with a `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`. The `SliverList` has to be scrollable horizontally. Also, it should have one header row that sticks to the top of the view.

Please see the example here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=38c0825f27c1b3395dd22794a2567e64. Note that the body can be scrolled horizontally.

I want to make the red header row sticky so that it remains visible at all times while the blue content is scrolling.

Problem is that the header row must be inside the `SingleChildScrollView` and the `SizedBox` because otherwise it would not have the required width. But once it is inside there I cannot make it sticky anymore.

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution ^^
use SliverPersistentHeader to make the red header row sticky  and use SliverList instead of ListView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final scrollController = ScrollController();
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        const CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
          largeTitle: Text('Search'),
        ),
        //CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(),
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
            minHeight: 20.0,
            maxHeight: 30.0,
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.red, child: Center(child:
            Text("red header "))),
          ),
        ),

        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            List.generate(80, (index) => Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              color: Colors.blueAccent.shade100,
              child: const Text('bar'),
            )),
          ),
        ),

       ],
    ),
  ),
);
   }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
   _SliverAppBarDelegate({
       required this.minHeight,
      required this.maxHeight,
      required this.child,
    });

    final double minHeight;
    final double maxHeight;
    final Widget child;

    @override
     double get minExtent => minHeight;

    @override
     double get maxExtent => math.max(maxHeight, minHeight);

    @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context,
      double shrinkOffset,
      bool overlapsContent) {
     return new SizedBox.expand(child: child);
      }

    @override
    bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
      return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
      minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
       child != oldDelegate.child;
    }
   }
```

Comment: One thing: When I scroll the list, first the navigation bar starts to shrink. Then I can scroll a bit into the list before the SliverPersistentHeader starts to shrink. Is there a way I can control this? Can the SliverPersistentHeader start shrinking immediately?

Comment: In SliverPersistentHeader Widget , you will find minHeight & maxHeight. If you want it to not shrink, minHeight & maxHeight should have the same value. ^^